# NMSSH: Socket connection successful but then fail to establishing SSH session

Tags: ssh, nmssh

I was able to SSH into my IoT device yesterday, but this morning when I try to connect it again. it fails to establish SSH session.

```
2021-08-25 09:25:53.501096-0400 [1387:464804] NMSSH: Socket connection to 192.168.77.30 on port 22 succesful
2021-08-25 09:25:53.551438-0400 [1387:464804] NMSSH: Failure establishing SSH session
It seems like socket connection success and then fails.
```

Any help is appreciated.